# Iterate Databases and Delete Query

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to iterate a table with database names in it, open the database, check if a query exists, if it does delete it, then import a query from the database this code is being executed from.  I keep getting a compile time error on the line of `Set badqueryname = "qry_InformationMailer"` and what I am trying to do with that is set the name of the query to delete.  This is the error that line throws

```
object required
```

Full syntax:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Base 1
Private Sub fur()
  Dim ws As DAO.Workspace
  Dim db As DAO.Database
  Dim qd As DAO.QueryDef
  Dim rstTableName As DAO.Recordset
  Dim myArray() As String
  Dim intArraySize As Integer
  Dim iCounter As Integer
  Dim qryLoop As QueryDef
  Dim exists As String
  Dim dbs As Database
  Dim badqueryname As String
  'Compile error of object required on below line
  Set badqueryname = "qry_InformationMailer"
  Set rstTableName = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tbl_Data")
  If Not rstTableName.EOF Then
    rstTableName.MoveFirst
    intArraySize = rstTableName.RecordCount
    iCounter = 1
    ReDim myArray(intArraySize)
    Do Until rstTableName.EOF
      myArray(iCounter) = rstTableName.Fields("ProgramName")
      iCounter = iCounter + 1
      rstTableName.MoveNext
    Loop
End If
If IsObject(rstTableName) Then Set rstTableName = Nothing
  Set qd = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qry_InformationMailer")
  Set ws = DBEngine(0)
  For l = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
    Set db = ws.OpenDatabase("C:\" & Trim(myArray(l)) & ".mdb")
    For Each qryLoop In CurrentDb.QueryDefs
        If qry.LoopName = badqueryname Then
            exists = "Yes"
            DoCmd.DeleteObject acQuery, badqueryname
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    On Error Resume Next
    db.CreateQueryDef qd.Name, qd.SQl
    db.Close
    Set db = Nothing
  Next l
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `Set` when you assign a value to a simple variable type.

```vb
'Set badqueryname = "qry_InformationMailer"
badqueryname = "qry_InformationMailer"
```

Or, if you wish, you could use `Let` instead of `Set`.

```vb
Let badqueryname = "qry_InformationMailer"
```

But I don't see `Let` used very often anymore.

Actually, in your code the value of *badqueryname* never changes again after you assign its value.  In other words, it's being used like a constant, so you could just make it a constant.

```vb
  Const badqueryname As String = "qry_InformationMailer"
```

One of those changes should eliminate that *object required* error.  However, then you will encounter an error with the undeclared *qry* in this line ...

```vb
If qry.LoopName = badqueryname Then
```

Add `Option Explicit` to your module's Declarations section and then run Debug->Compile from the VB Editor's main menu.

The compiler should also complain here because *l* is undeclared ...

```vb
For l = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
```

Fix anything the compiler complains about and then run Debug->Compile again.  Repeat until no more compile errors.